# Clojure: function will not return right

Tags: clojure

```
    (defn foo [n]
      (if (== 1 n)
        true
        )
      false
      )

    (if (true? (foo 1))
         (println "true")
         )
    (if (false? (foo 1))
      (println "false")
      )
```

This always return false, I assume that in clojure it only returns the last thing i write in the function. How can I break a loop and return something when the if condition is met?

Comment: Move paren after true to after false: `(if (== 1 n) true false)`. Also recommend getting an editor with formatting support, this is really hard to read (which may be why you didn't notice the problem yourself).

Comment: Look into IntelliJ+Cursive. As mentioned above, this is a bracing problem, and any code formatting would have made this obvious. Also, there's no loops here.

Comment: Also note that foo is equivalent to `(partial = 1)`.

Comment: In Clojure, you don't *break out* of a loop; you break into it again by using [`recur`](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` macro has the following format:

```
(if conditional-expression return-for-true return-for-false)
```

Your code is written like this:

```
(if conditional-expression return-for-true) return-for-false
```

Note the misplaced paren. Also note that unless the conditional expression is a function call no parens are needed.

Your foo function, as written, evaluates two expressions `(if ...)` and `false` and predictably returns the last evaluated expression, which is just the literal `false`. For a shorter and perhaps more easily-comprehended example of what's happening, consider this:

```
(defn foo [n] (+ 3 n) 4)
```

Calling this function will always return 4: the addition expression is either evaluated and not used or optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: You have extraneous parentheses around `(conditional-expression)`. Just as with the `then` and `else` branches, there are no decorative parens for the condition.

Comment: @amalloy made a clarifying edit. Wrote it that way because in the original question the conditional expression was a function call.

Comment: Edited to refer to *the `if` operator*, which is not a function.

Comment: @Thumbnail what's the distinction? I was under the impression that as a LISP dialect if is a function and occupies 'function position' in the list.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm following the terminology of the [Clojure Evaluation](https://clojure.org/reference/evaluation) page: **Non-empty Lists are considered calls to either special forms, macros, or functions. A call has the form (operator operands*).** As it happens, `if` is a special form. It certainly isn't a function, since its operands may not all be evaluated.  I believe other Lisps use similar terminology.

Comment: @Thumbnail makes perfect sense why you'd need a special form to avoid eager evaluation. Thank you for your edit.